# Hiding all Leaf Nodes while Showing Child Nodes on an ASP.Net Tree View

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview

In my website, I have a TreeView that has this structure:

```
Root
|-Leaf
|-Parent
|--Leaf 
|--Leaf
|--Child
|---Leaf
|---Leaf
|--Child
|---Leaf
|---Leaf
```

Is it possible to make the tree in a "collapsed" state where all the Leaf nodes and ONLY leaf nodes are hidden from view until its parent node is expanded? The ideal solution would be to do this without a postback, but any solution at this time would be helpful.

The "collapsed" view would look like this:

```
Root
|-Parent
|--Child
|--Child
```

Expanding the Root, Parent or Child nodes should show their Leaf nodes. Collapsing the node should re-hide its leaf nodes, but leave the child nodes visible.

Comment: There has to be something you can do in javascript using `var tree = $find('treeViewControl');` then using `var nodes = tree.get_allNodes()` and checking for childen of `nodes[i].get_nodes()`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a server-side (untested) solution:

```
TreeNodeCollection nodes = TreeView1.Nodes;
foreach (node in nodes)
{
   if (node.ChildNodes.Count == 0) 
   {
      node.Parent().Collapse();
   }
}
```

A client-side solution is definitely a preferred option.